# Embedding an OR statement in Index-Match not working

Tags: excel

I am using an Index-Match-Index formula (non-array) which works fine - until I embed an OR statement for one of the criteria.  Formula returns same result as if OR term is not there.

This works fine:
=INDEX(rng1,MATCH(1,INDEX((A1=rng2)*(B1=rng3)*(C1=rng4),0,1),0))

This does not:
=INDEX(rng1,MATCH(1,INDEX((A1=rng2)*(B1=rng3)*OR(C1=rng4,D1=rng4),0,1),0))

If I move the OR function to a helper column (and refer to the helper column in the first version of the formula) it works, but it would be tidier not to have to rely on helpers.

I feel like I must be missing some obvious detail...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make that formula an array formula and array formulas do not like OR operators. Simulate the OR operator using other methods.

As an array formula,

```
=INDEX(rng1, MATCH(1, INDEX((A1=rng2)*(B1=rng3)*sign((C1=rng4)+(D1=rng4)), 0, 1), 0))
```

As a standard formula,

```
=INDEX(rng1, aggregate(15, 7, row(rng1)/((A1=rng2)*(B1=rng3)*sign((C1=rng4)+(D1=rng4))), 1))
```

It is unlikely that you actually require the SIGN function since rng4 probably isn't going to equal C1 and D1 at the same time but it is there in the off chance that C1 and D1 are equal.

Comment: I have not seen that way to simulate OR I will try it...clarification:  I am deliberately avoiding array structure for INDEX-MATCH since my data set is too large.  Confirming that your suggestion will work for standard formula version?  Appreciate the help! M

Comment: If it wasn't a standard formula I wouldn't have noted it as such.

Comment: btw, row(rng1) will line up with index(rng1 when rng1 starts in row 1. If it doesn't, an adjustment according to the starting row in rng1 must be made. Your sample was just too oblique to offer a concrete solution.